# Intellij: Vagrant guest and host lines displayed as errors

Tags: ruby, intellij-idea, vagrant, vagrantfile

I have the following code in a Vagrant file:

```
  # Create a forwarded port mapping which allows access to a specific port
  # within the machine from a port on the host machine. In the example below,
  # accessing 'localhost:8080' will access port 80 on the guest machine.
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 9999, host: 9998
  config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3500, host: 3502
```

This code runs correctly, but Intellij thinks it is an error. I already installed a [Vagrant plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7379?pr=) in hopes that it would resolve the issue, but it does not.

How do I get Intellij to not mark the following two lines as errors when using Vagrant?

Answer (score 0):

Is your Vagrantfile associated to any particular types (you can check from your preferences under Editor > File Types)

If it is the case, you can change to associate as a text file and IntelliJ will not complain.

The vagrant plugin allows for interaction (start/stop ...) if you do not like to use a command line and vagrant command, but it has no support for the Vagrantfile